# Backbone model extending

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I would like to add some JSON to my existing backbone model. What is best approach to achieve this?

I tried following:

```
nextClick: function(event) {       
      //this.getPostData returns some JSON that I want to add in existing model
      this.model = new Backbone.Model.extend( this.getPostData() );
}
```

It doesn't work, `this.model` gives me following output in console:

```
console.log(this.model);
//output: function (){ parent.apply(this, arguments); }
```

Comment: `extend` returns a constructor function, not an `attributes` hash. Why aren't you using `Model.fetch` to update your model with data from the server?

Comment: Data is not coming from server, I'm stitching JSON on client. How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `Model.set` and pass in an an attributes hash. [From the docs](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-set):

```
note.set({title: "March 20", content: "In his eyes she eclipses..."});
```

This will set/create `title` and `content` in the note instance. So you should be able to

```
note.set(this.getPostData());
```

Answer (score 0):

you can write that

```
Model = new Backbone.Model.extend();
this.model = new Model(this.getPostData());
```